# GraalVM Java 8 SSLEngine only supports cipher suite TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV

Tags: java, ssl, java-8, graalvm

I've got this small little program

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        context.init(null, null, null);
        SSLEngine engine = context.createSSLEngine();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(engine.getSupportedCipherSuites()));
    }
}
```

And running on

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_302"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_302-b07)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM GraalVM LIBGRAAL 20.3.3 (build 25.302-b07-jvmci-20.3-b20, mixed mode)
```

will only report back

```
[TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
```

The provider is

```
SunJSSE version 1.8
```

The config in `jre/lib/security/java.security` does not seem to disable all the standard cipher suites

```
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1, RC4, DES, MD5withRSA, \
    DH keySize < 1024, EC keySize < 224, 3DES_EDE_CBC, anon, NULL, \
    include jdk.disabled.namedCurves
[...]
jdk.tls.legacyAlgorithms= \
        K_NULL, C_NULL, M_NULL, \
        DH_anon, ECDH_anon, \
        RC4_128, RC4_40, DES_CBC, DES40_CBC, \
        3DES_EDE_CBC
```

So where are all the TLS 1.2 and TLS 1.3 cipher suites? What else can be influencing the selection?

Comment: `openssl ciphers -v 'TLSv1.2'`
This should provide a list of cipher suites supported by OpenSSL on your machine for TLS 1.2. You may compare this list to the one returned by your software to determine if there are any differences.

Comment: @SyntaxNavigator There is no OpenSSL involved here.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce it, but if you put breakpoints in SSLEngineImpl, and SSLContextImpl, stepping through them it may just tell.

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: @Michael CentOS 8, linux kernel 5.12.

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce it (I get many cipher suites).

Comment: @Savior What architecture does your system have? pc, mac, arm? Do you run it inside somekind of virtualization (like docker, kvm, proxmox ...)?

Comment: @Lonzak It's bare metal linux. Weirdly enough, it's only a couple hosts among this fleet. But I fail to see what system setting could influence the JVM's selection of algorithms.

Comment: @Savior  I updated my answer with two additional points... (What architecture are you running?) And those fleet of other system are those completely identical or different in hard- or software?

Answer (score 0):

I've downloaded and tested your code with your GraalVM version on java 8 *(https://github.com/graalvm/graalvm-ce-builds/releases/tag/vm-20.3.3)*

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_302"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_302-b07)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM GraalVM CE 20.3.3 (build 25.302-b07-jvmci-20.3-b20, mixed mode)
```

I've this output :

```
[TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
```

I have check my $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/java.security :

```
  jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1, RC4, DES, MD5withRSA, \
        DH keySize < 1024, EC keySize < 224, 3DES_EDE_CBC, anon, NULL, \
        include jdk.disabled.namedCurves
    <...>
    jdk.tls.legacyAlgorithms= \
            K_NULL, C_NULL, M_NULL, \
            DH_anon, ECDH_anon, \
            RC4_128, RC4_40, DES_CBC, DES40_CBC, \
            3DES_EDE_CBC
```

So, I only see 2 possibilities if you have a fresh install :

1. you don't use *--enable-https* when you compile Java code to a standalone executable like this :

   ```
    $ native-image --enable-https Example
   ```
2. you have a problem on your system environment and this is not a GraalVM problem...

I hope it can help you,
GLHF !

Answer (score 0):

Some important information is missing in your post:

In a comment you write that your operating system is linux but on what **[architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Linux-supported_computer_architectures)** does it run? X86, MAC, ARM, ...? Do you run it inside some kind of **virtualization** layer (like docker, kvm, proxmox ...) or bare metal?

Several things come to mind:

1. You are using CentOS 8 with linux kernel 5.12. Cent OS 8 has been eol'ed since 2021-12-31 - [do not use it](https://vulners.com/thn/THN:A022718A54C5EE0C2378E2A496201F6C) anymore. There are known Java related [bugs](https://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=9482) in centOS.
2. You can try to enable a different provider like SunEC in java.security config file by adding the line `security.provider.9=sun.security.ec.SunEC` (You can find an overview of available providers [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html))
3. Did you try to use an up-to-date graalVM? The current java8 of graalVM is [20.3.10 - 8u371](https://docs.oracle.com/en/graalvm/enterprise/20/docs/overview/release-notes/) (enterprise). There have been bugfixes in this area (e.g. in 20.3.4) and also additions: [Sean Mullan announced](https://twitter.com/seanjmullan/status/1549461422286856193) that TLSv1.3 was enabled in 8u341 (which you are not using with 8u302)
4. Are you using java 8 for a specific reason? If not then use Java11 or higher. If yes then still try a Java11 based graal Version and see whether the behaviour is the same. (If you see more cipher suites this might be a java related issue if not then OS related)
5. Try to enable more cipher suites by using the `setEnabledCipherSuites` method, passing in an array of cipher suite names. For example:

   ```
   engine.setEnabledCipherSuites(new String[] {"TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256", "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384"});
   ```
6. You can always use a different SSL/TLS implementation, like Bouncy Castle, OpenSSL or the JSSE implementation that comes with a newer version of the JDK.
7. Try to add the following extension path to your java call: `-Djava.ext.dirs=./:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.302.b07_64/jre/lib/ext` (adapt the path accordingly) It should point to the folder where the `sunjce_provider.jar` etc is located
8. Did you enable debug output? `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl` What does it say?